# Literature on matrices with parametric elements

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am working on some quantum computing topics, and that led me to think about matrices whose elements are probabilistic or parametric in the sense that they can be written as $pa + (1-p)b$ where $p \in [0, 1]$ and $a, b$ are complex numbers. I could not find any relevant literature on this. Can someone point me towards any existing literature on such matrices, or does it even make sense to consider such matrices? Thanks!

Comment: If $pa+(1-p)b$ is just a complex number, as you say, then the matrix is in $M_n(\Bbb C)$. So no problem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But can we deduce any particular properties of such matrices? For example if we have a $n \times n$ matrix where each element is parameterized by a unique random variable, then what sort of statements can we make about such matrices?

Comment: I do know that know that if each entry of a your matrix is the outcome of a real continuous random variable, then probability your matrix has full rank equals $1$. What kind of properties are you looking for?

Comment: the parameterization is a little bit different but it sounds like you may be interested in path-connected groups

Comment: @MatthewPilling For example I was thinking if we can say anything about the invertibility of such matrices. But if they have full rank then I believe they are invertible. Can you point me towards any resources that show that they will have full rank?

Comment: @user8675309 I will look in to path-connected groups.

Comment: I can provide you with an elementary argument for this fact for a $2\times 2$ matrix. For each $(i,j)\in \{1,2\}^2$ let $X_{ij}$ be a continuous random variable with pdf $f_{ij}$ and set $$A=\begin{pmatrix}X_{11}&X_{12}\\ X_{21}&X_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$ Assume these $X_{ij}$'s are independent. The event that $A$ *doesn't* have full rank is precisely the event that $\det(A)=X_{11}X_{22}-X_{12}X_{21}=0$. Now $$P(\det(A)=0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X_{11}x=X_{12}X_{21}|X_{22}=x)f_{X_{22}}(x)dx$$ Let's assume $x,\epsilon>0$ where $\epsilon$ is very small.

Comment: It follows from independence that \begin{eqnarray*}
P(X_{11}x=X_{12}X_{21}|X_{22}=x) & = & P\Bigg(X_{11}=\frac{X_{12}X_{21}}{x}\Bigg)
\\ & \approx & P\Bigg(\Big|X_{11}-\frac{X_{12}X_{21}}{x}\Big|<\epsilon\Bigg) \\
 & = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{x_{12}x_{21}}{x}-\epsilon}^{\frac{x_{12}x_{21}}{x}+\epsilon}f_{X_{11}}(x_{11})f_{X_{12}}(x_{12})f_{X_{21}}(x_{21})dx_{11}dx_{12}dx_{21} \\ & \approx & 0
\end{eqnarray*} This probability will also evaluate to zero for any $x\leq 0$ which renders $P(\det(A)=0)=0$. The idea boils down to this:

Comment: If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are outcomes of continuous and independent random variables, the event that $\det(A)=0$ implies the $n^2$ entries of $A$ reside on a $n^2-1$ dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ which has no volume in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.